# Multiple \arrayrulecolor per line with booktabs

Tags: latex

Taking this to [tex.stackexhange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581170/how-to-omit-vertical-realignment-when-using-cmidrule-in-different-colors-and-wid).

### The problem

Let's say I want to have more than rules in two different colors in the same row ... how can I make it work?

Here is a minimal example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs} 


\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            \toprule
            A & B & alpha & beta\\
            \arrayrulecolor{black} \cmidrule[1pt](l){1-1} \arrayrulecolor{red} \cmidrule[1pt](r){2-2} \arrayrulecolor{black} \cmidrule[1pt](l){3-3} \arrayrulecolor{black} \cmidrule[1pt](r){4-4}
            1 & 5 & 10 &    100\\
            2 & 6 & 11 &    101\\
            2 & 7 & 12 &    102\\
            3 & 8 & 13 &    103\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

What happens is that with each call of `\arrayrulecolor{}`, the corresponding cmidrule is moved down. Is there a solution to this?

[image: result]

### The problem with the earlier solution

The solution mentioned in the comments has some trouble when you have different widths in one row. Consider this example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\newcommand{\corcmidrule}[1][2pt]{% \corcmidrule[<len>]
    \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip-\belowrulesep-\aboverulesep-#1\relax]%
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            \toprule
            A & B & alpha & beta\\
            \arrayrulecolor{black}\cmidrule[1pt](l){1-1} 
            \corcmidrule[2pt]\arrayrulecolor{black}\cmidrule[2pt](r){2-2} 
            \corcmidrule[5pt]\arrayrulecolor{black}\cmidrule[5pt](l){3-3} 
            \corcmidrule[1pt]\arrayrulecolor{black}\cmidrule[1pt](r){4-4}
            1 & 5 & 10 &    100\\
            2 & 6 & 11 &    101\\
            2 & 7 & 12 &    102\\
            3 & 8 & 13 &    103\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's wrong with this?
Consider what it looks like without the macro:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\newcommand{\corcmidrule}[1][2pt]{% \corcmidrule[<len>]
    \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip-\belowrulesep-\aboverulesep-#1\relax]%
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            \toprule
            A & B & alpha & beta\\
            \arrayrulecolor{black}\cmidrule[1pt](l){1-1} 
            \cmidrule[2pt](r){2-2} 
            \cmidrule[5pt](l){3-3} 
            \cmidrule[1pt](r){4-4}
            1 & 5 & 10 &    100\\
            2 & 6 & 11 &    101\\
            2 & 7 & 12 &    102\\
            3 & 8 & 13 &    103\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

The macro might need a modification.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35817/how-to-omit-vertical-realignment-when-using-cmidrule-in-different-colors

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I didn't use the right keywords in search. Solved.